# Usage Error When run "yarn start" on yarn berry project

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2

Our team decides to use **yarn berry** on our project, and one in my team initialize project. So I cloned the project on my local and run "yarn start" in terminal But it is not work.
This is the Error message.

**Usage Error: Couldn't find the node_modules state file - running an install might help (findPackageLocation)**

I tried "yarn install" and it worked but node_modules and other things are generated.

Comment: Is the .pnp.cjs and .yarnrc.yml file in the git repo? And please share the contents of yarnrc.yml file.

Answer (score -2):

You likely have to first do the command:

```
yarn install
```

Then

```
yarn start
```